# URL for pdf.js getDocument

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using pdf.js on an ASPX page on my website. The PDF file I'm trying to display is contained with the site, not on another server or another domain.

If I specify the PDF as any of the following, it opens correctly:

```
var url = 'MySample.pdf';
var url = '/MySample.pdf';
var url = '/Resources/MySample.pdf';
```

But if I use the following, it fails with a number of warning messages and then an error message:

```
var url = '/Resources/Products/MySample.pdf';
```

The error message is:

Uncaught (in promise): InvalidPDFException

Why can it not find my PDF file properly when it's down several folder levels from the site root folder?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Start from the very beginning of your site route. example.com"/blah/blah/resources/products/mysample.pdf" (include only quotation). If you already were, let me know.

Comment: Yes. Resources is a folder in the root of my site. In the each case I noted, I was putting the PDF in the appropriate folder, so it should have been able to find it. I also tried putting http-colon-slash-slash-localhost-colon-portnumber at the beginning of the url string, but that didn't work either.

Comment: try just loading the pdf in your browser first, then get back to me.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I have a case in my URL rewriter that was trapping certain PDF files and redirecting them, and I had forgotten that that code was in there. When I rename the PDF file, pdf.js is working fine. Sorry to bother you! Thanks for trying to help solve my problem!

Comment: No problem. Have fun coding.